# Replicating Excel function INDEX in R

Tags: r, excel, data.table, match, vlookup

I'm trying to replicate Excel's 'INDEX'-function in R, unfortunately I couldn't adjust any of the solutions provided on this board to solve my issue.
My first table contains the column and row indices based on which values are selected from the second table:

```
library(data.table)
table1<-data.table(data.frame(RowIndex = c(1,2,4,3), ColumnIndex = c(2,3,1,1)))
table2<-data.table(data.frame(columnAD = c("a","b","c","d"), columnEH = c("e","f","g","h"), columnIL = c("i","j","k","l")))
table1$MatchedData<-c("e","j","d","c")
```

My desired ouput as in Excel is added as 'MatchedData'. So far I've tried different combinations with match or ifelse, but none were successful.
Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Does this question include all the data you need to make it reproducible? [reprex] perhaps you could set out the rules or process by which the `MatchedData` vector is generated from the other tables.

Comment: I have scaled down the dimensions of the tables quite a bit, but generating 

´´´
MatchedData
´´´

Essentially boils down to translating

´´´
=INDEX(Table2!$B$2:$D$5,A2,B2)
´´´
Or
´´´
=INDEX(array, row_num, [column_num])
´´´

To R. 
But until now I couldn’t adjust @Ian Campbell ‘s solution to my specific data, so I might be overlooking something.

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to use `by=` to subset `table2` for every row of `table1`:

```
library(data.table)
table1[, Result := table2[RowIndex, ColumnIndex, with = FALSE],
       by = seq_len(nrow(table1))][]
   RowIndex ColumnIndex Result
1:        1           2      e
2:        2           3      j
3:        4           1      d
4:        3           1      c
```

Note that `[]` just prints `table1` after assignment by reference with `:=`.

Answer (score 0):

Using base R matrix numeric indexing:

```
as.matrix(table2)[as.matrix(table1)]
```